# VBS How to replace any color string (#******) with new value

Tags: replace, colors, vbscript

trying to replace in a folder different color values with a new one  this is my starting code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, strFolder, objFolder, objFile
Dim strOldValue, strNewValue, objRead, strContents, objWrite
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
strFolder = "..\..\chrome\OPCEN\TABS"
strOldValue = "#******"
strNewValue = "#F5F5F5"
```

UPDATE: this is the working code using RegEx (but is pointing to the file not to the whole folder)

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("..\..\chrome\OPCEN\TABS\tabs.css", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

objRegEx.Global = True   
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = False
objRegEx.Pattern = "\#[A-Z 0-9]{6}"

strNewText =  objRegEx.Replace(strText, "#F5F5F5")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("..\..\chrome\OPCEN\TABS\tabs.css", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText

objFile.Close
```

Comment: I think you can use a regex to capture either the start of the string or a whitespace char and match a hexedecimal value. In the replacement, use group 1 and the new value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBscript regex replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859541/vbscript-regex-replace). *Example of using the `RegExp` object to replace match values based on a RegEx pattern.*

Comment: I updated the question with the working code Thanks again

Comment: @frankell So you want to scan and replace all strings in all files `*.css` in a folder or any files with any extensions ?

Comment: well I would like to have also the folder chance, actually all the files in the folders are .css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [For Each](https://ss64.com/vb/foreach.html) loop to processing files and [Regular Expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_reg_expressions.htm) to replace your strings.

Try my way :

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set fso=Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objRegEx = New RegExp

FolderName = "..\..\chrome\OPCEN\TABS"

Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderName)
Set objFileCol = objFolder.Files

For Each obFile In objFileCol

If Right(obFile,3)="css" Then 'Check all files extensions.
Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(obFile, ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

objRegEx.Global = True   
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = False
objRegEx.Pattern = "\#[A-Z 0-9]{6}"

strNewText =  objRegEx.Replace(strText, "#F5F5F5")
Set WriteFile = fso.OpenTextFile(obFile, ForWriting)
WriteFile.WriteLine strNewText
WriteFile.Close
End if

Next
```

Comment: See my new changes